# How to return value in Meteor.JS from HTTP.call "GET"

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm writing a meteor method, which should return a Facebook response for `HTTP.call` on graph api, but `HTTP.call` has only a callback function to show error/response, so I can't take this data outside, and Method can not return any value.

Here's my method code:

```
loadUserFBEvents: function () {
  var accessToken = Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken;
  var query = "me?fields=likes.limit(5){events{picture,cover,place,name,attending_count}}";
  console.log(
    HTTP.call("GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/" + query + "&access_token=" + accessToken + "", function(error,response){
      if(error){
        return error;
      }
      if(response){
        return response;
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Response = data. If your response is null, you must be making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Response is indeed returning proper data from request, but entire HTTP.call does not return it to console.log which is wrapping entire HTTP.call

Comment: Yeah, thats awkward. Just do console.log(response), there's no reason (?) to console.log a whole method. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve in short: `loadUserFBEvents: function () {return HTTP.call(...)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't pass a callback to get the HTTP to return. You're also able to pass off URL parameters quite easily:

```
var result = HTTP.call("GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/me", {
    params: {
        access_token : Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken,
        fields : "likes.limit(5){events{picture,cover,place,name,attending_count}}"
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either log or use the response from inside the callback or use Meteor.wrapAsync to make it synchronous so that it returns the way you're expecting it to above.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync